# HTAccess rewrite rule ignored when using encoded url as a parameter

Tags: .htaccess, web

I have the following rule in my htaccess file which works fine except when the parameter is an encoded url

```
RewriteRule ^data/(.+)$ ?dataId=$1 [L]
```

If I pass an encoded URL like this the rule is ignored

https://example.com/data/https%3A%2F%2FsomeOtherUrl.com

It looks like %2F is causing this rule to be ignored.
Any idea on how to handle this?

Thanks

EDI: BTW this URL works fine. Only the htaccess redirection doesn't work

https://example.com/?dataId=https%3A%2F%2FsomeOtherUrl.com

Comment: This is probably not the fault of your RewriteRule, I’m guessing the request does not even make it this far, because [`AllowEncodedSlashes`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#allowencodedslashes) is set to `off` …?

Comment: AllowEncodedSlashes is enabled. As explained in my post this works fine with the following URL: https://example.com/?dataId=https%3A%2F%2FsomeOtherUrl.com        My only issue if to set up the redirection